# Multiple Joins With Condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `params` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `parameter` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `entry` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `param_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `value` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `access_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `enabled` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `param_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `params` (`id`, `parameter`) VALUES
  ('1','Height'),
  ('2', 'Weight'),
  ('3', 'Texture'),
  ('4', 'Colour');
 INSERT INTO `entry` (`id`, `param_id`,`value`,`access_id`) VALUES
  ('1','1','5.2','1'),
  ('2','2','80','2'),
  ('3','1','6','2');


 INSERT INTO `enabled` (`id`, `param_id`) VALUES
  ('1','1'),('2','2');
```

I am trying to get all parameter values with `access_id` of 1 from the `entry` table 
OR
All Parameters that are `enabled` which (DOES NOT exist in the `entry` table with `access_id`of 1)

So the output should be

```
id  parameter   value   access_id
1   Height        5      1
2   Weight       NULL    NULL
```

The second entry here has a value of null because although it is `enabled` it does not have an `access_id` of 1 in the `entry` table
The schema here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/103016

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Have you tried the obvious joins and then just ORing the conditions you've proposed in the WHERE?

Comment: Why are 3 and 4 missing? Define 'enabled'

Comment: This is the same as your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60647747/multiple-sql-join-on-condition). If you think that shouldn't have been closed, edit the question and ask for it to be reopened.

Comment: sorry i am adjusting the schema has been updated, strawberry is right

Comment: Only Weight and Texture are enabled

Comment: (All params with access_id = 1) OR (All rows which are enabled that do not have an entry with access_id of 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select p.*, e.value, e.access_id from params p
inner join entry e on p.id= e.param_id and e.access_id = 1
union 
select p.*, null,null from params p
inner join enabled enb on p.id=enb.param_id
where enb.param_id not in (select param_id from entry where access_id = 1)
```